# ajax. how to invoke javascript code from requested html file

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have the *index.html* page.

Inside that page i have javascript code that makes a button to evoke ajax request for the *other.html* to be shown inside a div in *index.html* .

The *other.html* have nothing else but a div ( that contains the content ) and some javascript code.

The *other.html* loads normally inside the *index.html* but the javascript code does not work.

Anyone know why is this happening?

Thank you.

( the javascript code is as simple as an *alert("hello")* message ).

code:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src=main.js></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="to_change">bla bla bla</div>
<div id="button">click me</div>
</body>
<html>
```

main.js:

```
...
...
function sendRequest()
{
    request.open("GET","other.html",true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){

            var response = request.responseText;

            if(response) {
                document.getElementById("to_change").innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
}

....button.click(...sendRequest...);
...
...
```

other.html

```
<script type=...>alert("hello");</script>
<div>text text text text</div>
```

Comment: How is index.html loading the ajax page, and more importantly, how is the javascript placed in other.html? Could you please post your code.

Comment: You really should provide the code you are using. If you are using JQuery, the code in the `script` tag will be stripped out. It would be best to put the javascript in your `index.html`.

Comment: i edited some simple code because the original is too long. does that help?

Answer (score 0):

javascript is loading but function call is not happening.

You are not calling the functions in any event.

```
<BODY onLoad="alert('hello world!')">
```

Like this try to call the function . On any event you want

Comment: but where should i write the event? in index.html or other html? it doesn't seem to work neither way

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove the enclosing '`<doctype...>`', '`<html>`', and '`<body>`' tags from the "other.html" file, in case they are present.

Comment: yes i have removed them. but i don't think it makes any change

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the scripts manually:

```
// ...
if (response) {
  var toChange=document.getElementById("to_change"), scripts, i;
  toChange.innerHTML = response;
  scripts = toChange.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for (i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    eval(scripts[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Of course, eval is *evil*, so use at your own risk...